# How to fill a datagridview cell from another form ? C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, delegates, invoke

I'm a beginer in C# and for now the most difficult thing to me is to understand how to pass data and modify objects from a form/class to another form/class. I understand that I should use event or delegate but I'm not sure how to use it yet.

For now, I have a datagridview (with Column_Name, Column_Age etc) in my Form1, and in my Form2, I have some textboxs that the user will fill and validate with a button.

I want that when the user press the validate button in Form2, the textbox text goes to to a cell of my datagridview in Form1, on the last row.

Example:

(Form1)

- User write "Henri" in `textbox_Name`, "52" in `textbox_Age`, etc
- He validates by clicking on `button1`

(Form2)

- When the user has validate by clicking on button1 (Form2), each cell in the last index row (a new row) gets the corresponding value of the textbox. Example : `datagridview1[*newrow.Index*,Column_Name.Index] = textbox_Name.Text.ToString();` `datagridview1[*newrow.Index*,Column_Age.Index] = textbox_Age.Text.ToString();` etc

not sure about the *newrow.Index*

Thanks ! If you have some good links to help me on that, I'll take!

Comment: `var newRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();` returns the index of the new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found a solution. Let me know if you would have done otherwise.

In `Form1.cs` :

```
private static Form1 _Form1;

public static Form1 GetInstance()
{
    if (_Form1 == null)
    {
        _Form1 = new Form1();
    }
    return _Form1;
}
```

In `Form2.cs` :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.GetInstance().dataGridView1[Form1.GetInstance().Column_Name.Index, Form1.GetInstance().dataGridView1.Rows.Add()].Value = textbox_Name.Text.ToString();
    Form1.GetInstance().dataGridView1[Form1.GetInstance().Column_Age.Index, Form1.GetInstance().dataGridView1.Rows.Add()].Value = textbox_Age.Text.ToString();
}
```